# Angular 6 Need to open new tab from componenent with new builded html (included input data)

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Good day, everyone.

From the modal component that will input some data  I need open new browser tab with resulted HTML that will contain formatted input data, example of code (i simplify it and try to use ng-template instead of one more component that should include resulted html):

```
@Component({
   template:
        '<p class="error" (click)="this.openValidationWarningsInNewWindow(hello)">Validation Warnings - click to see details</p>\n' +
        '\n' +
        '<ng-template #hello>\n' +
        '  <div>formatedData: someData.value</div>\n' +
        '</ng-template>\n'
})
export class ValidationMessageComponent {
   @Input() someData: DataModel;

   @ViewChild('hello') helloEl: ElementRef;

   private openValidationWarningsInNewWindow(content: any) {
      const newWindow = window.open('about:blank', '_blank');
      let hell = this.helloEl.nativeElement as HTMLElement;
      newWindow.document.write(hell.innerText);
      newWindow.document.title = 'Validation Warnings';
      newWindow.document.close();
   }
}
```

Sure, the way described in example doesn't work, at least I'm not able to get interHTML of nativeElement. 
 In new tab, i need just html representation (it's could be just simple HTML, but in this tab this html should included binded data)
Although, the way with [routerLink] and '_blank' target doesn't work, cause I need to transfer binding data.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: I simplify my example, in best way i wanna use separate component instead of  <ng-template #hello>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you can  beautify your template code wrapped by ``` `` ```

and you don't need to  add `"\n"` any more

for Example:

`` `<p class="error" (click)="this.openValidationWarningsInNewWindow(hello)">Validation Warnings - click to see details</p>` ``

Then let's fix your problem:

you can define some route and component to render the innerHTML

For Example:

You defined a route called '/dynamic_html'

and it's component's template like this:

```
<div [innerHTML]="MY_HTML"></div>
```

You can link to this route by `window.open('/dynamic_html')` or any other solution.

Don't forget to [sanitize](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer) your html.

happy coding !

Comment: excuse me, but i didn't get your answer. Do u mean, that i'm able to use [innerHtml] for bounding and later put it into newWindow.document.write(innerHTML) ?>

Comment: No, What I mean is you can pass your html data in other new route that you can parse it in that component.

Comment: actually my aim, it's open simple html in new window, but before it, i need to build this html (from template with buinding). how i understood u propose to create separate component tat will be open in new window through routerLink - but in this case i need to transfer input data into this component. Possible i mess your idea, could u simplify demonstrate it in plunker ?>

Comment: i read more about [innerHTML] and it's not my case, coz "MY_HTML" will be the same string, that i able directly past into the  newWindow.document.write(MY_HTML) and open it in separate tab.